# ErrorTemplate for StackPanel

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Currently, my Business Object looks like this:

```
    public class FooBar : IDataErrorInfo
    {
        public Int32 TextBoxProperty1 { get; set; }
        public Int32 TextBoxProperty2 { get; set; }
        public Int32 TextBoxProperty3 { get; set; }
        public Int32 TextBoxProperty4 { get; set; }
        public Int32 Total{ get; set; }

        public override Boolean Validate()
        {
            if (Total < 100)
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }

            return true;
        }

        public string Error
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public string this[String propertyName]
        {
            get 
            {
                if (propertyName == "Total")
                    if (Validate())
                        return "Error";

                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Now currently in my XAML (which is in a `ResourceDictionary`) my DataTemplate holds 4 TextBoxes where each `TextBox` is bound to `TextBoxProperty1`, `TextBoxProperty2`, `TextBoxProperty3` , `TextBoxProperty4`. What I really want is that if the values do not sum up to 100, that a red Border is displayed around the StackPanel, of which contains the 4 `TextBoxes`. My XAMl will look something like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate">
        <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource errorSPStyle}">
            <StackPanel.DataContext>
                <Binding Path="Parameter" Mode="TwoWay" ValidatesOnExceptions="True" NotifyOnValidationError="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
            </StackPanel.DataContext>
            <pres:TextBox Width="40">
                    <pres:TextBox.Text>
                        <Binding Path="Parameter.TextBoxProperty1" Mode="TwoWay" ValidatesOnExceptions="True" NotifyOnValidationError="True">
                        </Binding>
                    </pres:TextBox.Text>
                </pres:TextBox>
            <pres:TextBox Width="40">
                    <pres:TextBox.Text>
                        <Binding Path="Parameter.TextBoxProperty2" Mode="TwoWay" ValidatesOnExceptions="True" NotifyOnValidationError="True">
                        </Binding>
                    </pres:TextBox.Text>
                </pres:TextBox>
            <pres:TextBox Width="40">
                    <pres:TextBox.Text>
                        <Binding Path="Parameter.TextBoxProperty3" Mode="TwoWay" ValidatesOnExceptions="True" NotifyOnValidationError="True">
                        </Binding>
                    </pres:TextBox.Text>
                </pres:TextBox>
            <pres:TextBox Width="40">
                    <pres:TextBox.Text>
                        <Binding Path="Parameter.TextBoxProperty4" Mode="TwoWay" ValidatesOnExceptions="True" NotifyOnValidationError="True">
                        </Binding>
                    </pres:TextBox.Text>
                </pres:TextBox>
```

Any way I can get the Style to be applied on my `StackPanel` instead of on the `TextBox`? I know that the `Binding` should be `OneWay` on the `StackPanel` since you can't really modify the source.

Comment: Please delete all that immediately and use an `ItemsControl`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is possible using the IDataErrorInfo interface alone - I think that is primarily aimed at binding individual properties to controls such as textboxes, and providing validation feedback to those controls.

One option would be to expose a boolean property on your BO (which would also need to implement INPC), i.e.

```
public bool IsValid
{
    get { return _isValid; }
    set
    {
        if (_isValid != value)
        {
            _isValid = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsValid");
        }
    }
}
```

You would set this property value to true or false from within the `this[]` property.

In your xaml, create a style with a DataTrigger to style a border around the StackPanel, e.g.:-

```
<Style x:Key="BorderStyle" TargetType="Border">
  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"/>
  <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
  <Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsValid}" Value="False">
      <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
    </DataTrigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Border Style="{StaticResource BorderStyle}">
   <StackPanel ..etc..
</Border>
```

Comment: Going to be giving this a shot

Comment: This definitely works, but I was wondering if it's still a posibility to place a red border around a group of controls. It doesn't have to be a StackPanel. Is there another way?